# Is there a easy way to deploy ror on windows?not a development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are many guide help us to deploy ROR on windows for development.
How can I to deploy a ROR evironment for production.
The InstantRails project doesn't update anymore,and I don't know is it can be use for regular production?

Comment: I'd like to ask what is the reason to use Windows as production platform to server Rails?

Comment: we had an experience to move Rails production environment from Windows to Linux box. We used MS Office OLE before, but rewrite the parser with Spreadsheet gem. The performance by bechmarks and NewRelic was  impressive! Linux box setup is 2-3 times faster than we had on Windows platform

Comment: I only have a Widnows 2003 computer to be server.

Comment: do you able to setup virtual machine as a guest OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the installer found here for Ruby- http://rubyinstaller.org/

Just don't install the dev kit add on.  Then install the gem manager (same page) and do gem install rails.  That should get you stated.

-Will

Comment: Thank you very much.The "don't install the dev kit" really help for me.